# Remove Trailing Zeros from a Hexadecimal string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of Hexadecimal strings with many TRAILING zeros.
The problem i have is that the trailing Zeros from the string,  needs to be removed

I have searched for a VBA formula such as Trim but my solution has not worked.

Is there a VBA formula I  can use to remove all these Trailing zeros from each of the strings.
An example of the HEX string is 4153523132633403277E7F0000000000000000000000000000. I would like to have it in a format of 4153523132633403277E7F

The big issue is that the Hexadecimal strings can be of various lengths.

Comment: The "Reduce" formula did the trick... Thankyou !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Formula:**

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
  =LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"0"),TEXTJOIN("0",0,TAKE(a,XMATCH("?*",a,2,-1))))
```

This would `TEXTSPLIT()` the input and the fact that we can then use `XMATCH()` to return the position of the last non-empty string with a wildcard match `?*`. However, given the fact we can use arrays in our `TEXTSPLIT()` function, a little less verbose could be:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"0",,1)),,-1),-1)
```

Or another option, though more verbose, is to use `REDUCE()` for what it's intended to do, which is to loop a given array:

```
=REDUCE(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(RIGHT(a)="0",LEFT(a,LEN(a)-1),a)))
```

---

**VBA:**

If VBA is a must, one way of dealing with this is through the `RTrim()` function. Since your HEX-string should not contain spaces to begin with I think the following is a safe bet:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "4153523132633403277E7F0000000000000000000000000000"
Dim s_new As String

s_new = Replace(RTrim(Replace(s, "0", " ")), " ", "0")

Debug.Print s_new

End Sub
```

If you happen to have spaces anywhere else in your string, another option would be to look for trailing zero's using a regular expression:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "4153523132633403277E7F0000000000000000000000000000"
Dim s_new As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "0+$"
    s_new = .Replace(s, "")
End With

Debug.Print s_new

End Sub
```

Both the above options should print: `4153523132633403277E7F`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no function to do that for you. The way I would do it is presented in the pseudo-code below:

```
while last character is "0"
    remove last character
end while
```

It is quit slow, but VBA itself is not race car either, so you will probably not notice especially if you do not need to that for many times at once.

A more beautiful solution would involve VBA being able to search for the beginning or the end of a string.

An **improvement** of the solution above is to parse the string backwards and count the "0" characters, and then remove them all at the same time.